# UITapGestureRecognizer error in UIlabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am use `UITapGestureRecognizer` on `UILabel`.

But when I tap on `UILabel` it crash.

**Following is my code.**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gester = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveToDetail:)];
gester.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[label addGestureRecognizer:gester];
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

**Following is moveToDetail method**

```
- (void)moveToDetail:(id)sender {
}
```

**Following is crash message**

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITapGestureRecognizer
>   rootViewIfClass:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

How to resolve this.

Comment: can you try to update your selector method's parameter from "id" to "uitapgesturerecognizer".

Comment: Tried your code with a new project, the code executed successfully without any crash

Comment: Please show how did you declare `label`.

Comment: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan I am also use in different place it working fine.

Comment: Then please check your code, the place its crashing are there any other gesture recogniser?

Comment: I try to change "id" to "uitapgesturerecognizer" and it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks all of you to suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  code

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gester = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveToDetail)];
gester.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[label addGestureRecognizer:gester];

- (void)moveToDetail
{

}
```